# Camel get session in processor

Tags: java, session, apache-camel

I am trying to retrieve a session object after calling a camel processor. My route gets called by using the restlet component and then eventually uses the http4 component to retrieve html.

```
 <route>
        <from uri="restlet:/v1/html"/>
        <process ref="validateSessionProcessor"/>                                    
        <recipientList>
            <simple>https4://www.google.com/?bridgeEndpoint=true</simple>
        </recipientList>
    </route>
```

From the documentation it seems easy to keep the session when using the jetty component: http://camel.apache.org/jetty.html

After setting the session support to true you can easily retrieve the session in a processor

```
<from uri="jetty:http://0.0.0.0/myapp/myservice/?sessionSupport=true"/>
```

And in java:

```
HttpSession session = exchange.getIn(HttpMessage.class).getRequest().getSession();
```

But that does not seem to be the case for the components I am using.

I found in the http4 component documentation there will be support coming in camel 2.19

> Camel 2.19: Configure a cookie handler to maintain a HTTP session

And the documentation already exists here: http://camel.apache.org/http-session-handling.html

Is there anyway to get the session in my scenario using the components I use?

Comment: I am not even sure if Restlet provides anything like a HttpSession. Can you look at Restlet and see what they offer in this regard.

Comment: @ClausIbsen the same as the HTTP4 documentation, it says Camel 2.19 ,unfortunately. http://camel.apache.org/restlet.html

Comment: I mean at restlet.org itself and what session information it provides (if at all). And check camel-restlet source code to see what its stored in message/exchange as there is maybe some restlet objects there that gives you access to session (if possible). And btw what is your use-case for needing http session?

Comment: @ClausIbsen  btw, is there any example how to enable a SessionManager for those who use Rest with Jetty like me?..

Comment: sorry, found out myself: `restConfiguration.setEndpointProperties(options)`